# How to prevent access to folder in Apache2 and allow access in PHP?

Tags: php, directory, apache2, apache2.4

I know this question has been asked several times, however I tried many combinations and none appears to be working.

This is a section from my `apache.conf` file:

```
<Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -Indexes -FollowSymLinks -ExecCGI
    AllowOverride Limit

    # Restrict access controls to all HTTP methods except the named ones (GET)
    <LimitExcept GET>
        Require all denied
    </LimitExcept>

    # Restrict access controls to the GET HTTP method, by only allowing
    # requests coming from the specified IPs
    <Limit GET>
        # Clients in the specified IP address ranges can access the resource,
       Require ip <list of IPs here>
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

How do I configure `apache.conf` file so that directory `/var/www/html/somefolder` is not accessible from the outside but it is accessible from PHP scripts running on the server?

I tried adding this right below the above code:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/denied_directory>
    Order allow,deny
    <Files some_private_file.txt>
        Order deny,allow
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I also tried with `Files` and `Location`, but they either do not work (that is, clients from the outside are still being able to access the folder) or they work *too well* (that is, PHP scripts are not able to access the folder and files).

Thank you in advance to anyone who will spend some of his/her time trying to help me.

Comment: The simplest answer is to move `denied_directory` up one level to  `/var/www/` assuming you defined the `DocumentRoot` as `/var/www/html`

Comment: I understand this, @AlexBarker. However, I am still curious to know how to achieve what I asked without moving the `denied_directory`.